# Iobit programs slow down my windows boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

My Acer V Nitro is a really good notebook and the time for Windows boot used to be something like 5 ~ 10 seconds. Hoping to improve this I installed Iobit Advanced System Care and Iobit Disk Defrag, but they ruined everything.

Now my boot took more than 1 minute.

Can I revert this in a way that is not system restore? Some configuration change, some Windows registry?

Thanks

Comment: System Restore probably won't do it either, given that Restore is not sensitive to file location on disk.  I would suggest using a whole-disk backup program to back up, then restore the whole thing back.  Windows 10 has one built in; do some research for Windows 10 System Image.  It may be more worth your while to do targeted backups and a clean format.

Comment: Actually I'm searching for a solution more simple than a system format. But thanks @ChristopherHostage

Comment: @Max what settings did you change with those apps? And why did you install those bad softwares?

Comment: I istalled because in my company they did a great job, but not in my personal machine as well. I dont know the exactly configurations because they did an automatic list of recovery and fix solutions. Cganges like privacy, system, etc.